# Как подключить две библиотеки для ботов телеграм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, telethon

Как взаимодействовать pyTelegramBotAPI и telethon в одном боте?

Answer (score 1):

это не самая лучшая идея
но если так хочется
то

1. импортируете в код 2 библиотеки
2. создаете два обьекта класса этих библиотек (для telebot это telebot.Telebot('токен'))(создавайте с разными названиями)
3. прописываете каждый хандле под ту библиотеку, что нужно

НО:

могут появляться конфликты

могут срабатывать не те хандлеры

Так что не советую так делать,но дело ваше

Comment: У меня основной библиотекой является telebot, но у telethon есть метод который нужно периодически вызывать. Я думал может инициализировать экземпляр класса в другом потоке и там запускать телетон?

Comment: если этот метод срабатывает на какой то тригер, то необязательно в другой поток,если он вызывается в определнное время,то да нужно прописать его в другом потоке

Comment: Смотрите, я написал модуль, туда импортировал либу telethon, инициализировал экземпляр, а вот когда программа вызывает этот модуль, он выдает ошибку ‘RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread “WorkerThread”’.

Comment: Поэтому я думал засунуть это в поток и там крутить библиотеку telethon.

Comment: судя по документации что-то в вашем коде пытается использовать asyncio в потоках. можете прикрепить код к вопросу

Comment: Бот работает нормально пока не дойдет до вызова модуля. Могу написать сам модуль, но это пример из документации telethon

Comment: можете тогда оставить ссылку на пример,который пытаетесь воиспрозвести с документации в коментариях

Comment: https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=CheckChatInviteRequest

Comment: дело в том что telethon асинхронная библиотека,и очень нежелательно использовать многопоточность и асинхронность вместе,без весомых на то причин,но если вам так это нужно то почитайте статьи о работе asynsio в потоках

Comment: А что посоветуете? Мне нужно найти chat_id чата который хочет добавить пользователь в раздел «мои чаты», а пересланные сообщения из этого чата не дают мне этих данных. Хочется обойтись малой кровью и воспользоваться готовыми решениями.

Comment: Возможно эта функция есть в telebot изучите более подробно эту библиотеку,если все таки нет,можно напрямую отправлять request на сервера телеги, почитайте об том методе тут https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.checkChatInvite

Comment: Я не понял как отправлять реквесты с этим методом

Comment: URL запроса https://api.telegram.org/bot{ТОКЕН БОТА}/{НАЗВАНИЕ МЕТОДА}

Comment: Res = requests.get(api.telegram.org/bot{ТОКЕН БОТА}/{НАЗВАНИЕ МЕТОДА}=hash) вот так же отправлять?

Comment: Я не работал с данным методом и не уверен,как правильно его использовать, я выше оставил ссылку на документацию телеграм,там все достаточно подробно описано) так же могу посоветовать почитать исходники этой функции в telethon и посмотреть как там это реализовано

Comment: Незнаю, что вы там видите понятного

Comment: в любом случае рано или поздно придется учиться читать и понимать документацию

Comment: Простите за тупой вопрос, а нужно передавать какие-то параметры кроме ссылки?

Comment: Это зависит от метода,в каких то нужно,в каких то нет, где то Post Запросы где то get? все это индивидулаьно для каждого метода и в документации расписано